# MySQL handling over 24h date format

Tags: mysql, sql, gtfs

I'm currently working with a data set that has time formatted over 24h, for example, `27:20:01 (which is 03:20:01)`. I've been using a query like this `STR_TO_DATE(stop_times.arrival_time, "%H:%i:%s") >= STR_TO_DATE("03:14:46", "%H:%i:%s")`

to get dates that are not older than current time, but since some dates are formatted over 24h `STR_TO_DATE` doesn't work. What is the best approach for time formatted like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
STR_TO_DATE(
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(stop_times.arrival_time, 1, 2) % 24, 
        SUBSTRING(stop_times.arrival_time, 3, 8)), "%H:%i:%s")
>= STR_TO_DATE("03:14:46", "%H:%i:%s")
```